# Broken image with bootstrap default navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a relative link to an image on my computer on which I'm developing a ruby on rails app. I'm using Bootstrap to customize the style and have used their code to source the image for the top left brand placement. Here's the bootstrap link to what I'm referring to: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

I'm trying to add a custom brand image, but I keep getting a broken image error (404 file not found) when I open my localhost:3000 to test in my browser. Not sure if this is an image size issue or a novice file location error. I have tried several types of images (jpg, jpeg, png, etc.) and different image sizes, but I keep getting the same error. This is a basic HTML/CSS error, and I'm struggling to figure out how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Below is my partial _header.html.erb file in which I reference the Bootstrap navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img alt="Humanify" src="../../app/assets/images/Logo_final_march2015.jpg">
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
....
```

Comment: When the header is included, relative paths are relative to the including document, not the included one. Best use absolute paths, if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).

Try something similar to this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <%= image_tag "Logo_final_march2015.jpg" %>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This solved the problem for me, but it resulted in a huge, full-size image and didn't automatically re-format to the right size. Any thoughts on this? Wish I could upvote but I still need rep points :)

Comment: Well I don't think there's a way around it. You will have to resize the image manually. Even though you could resize it with css that would be a bad idea because client would still need to load the full size image, which is slow.